# Can't dump sql table, unknown storage engine

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to dump an sql database for a client, but I keep getting an error.

`Couldn't execute 'show create table 'inc' unknown storage engine`. I tried

--lock-tables=false option, but still the same thing. I also tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ENGINE=SPHINX;') AS sql_statements 
FROM information_schema.tables AS tb 
WHERE table_schema = @DATABASE_NAME 
AND `ENGINE` = 'MyISAM' 
AND `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE' 
ORDER BY table_name DESC
```

The query executed, but still the same error when dumping. any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Silly question, but do you have `SPHINX` engine installed?

Comment: probably not. does that mean I cannot convert it to standart engine tables? thanks!

Comment: You may want to try installing - http://www.pythian.com/blog/using-the-sphinx-search-engine-with-mysql/